# Jquery .animate jump issue

Tags: jquery, flexslider

Long time listener, 1st time caller.  I have a site http://www.rivingtondesignhouse.com.php53-3.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/

i want to have flex slider animate down - I prefer this effect to slidedown which I got working no problem.    The problem is that when the slider appears it causes a jump.  How can we remove this jump?

Here is some of my  jquery

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#home-slider').css("display", "none");

    var realH = $("#home-slider").width() * 0.4;
    $("#home-slider").height(realH);
    $('#home-slider').css('display', 'block');
    $('#home-slider').css('height', 'auto');
    $('#home-slider').addClass('bump2');
    $('#home-slider').animate({
        marginTop: '-44%'
    }, 10);
    $('#home-slider').removeClass('bump2');
    $('#home-slider').animate({
        marginTop: '0'
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
});
```

Here is the css:

```
#home-slider.flexslider {
    background: url("images/slider-loader.gif") no-repeat scroll 50% 50% #FFFFFF;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position:relative;
}
.bump2 {
    position: relative !important;
    padding-bottom: 44% !important;
}
```

Here is some html

```
    <div id="home-slider" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">

        <li>
          <img src="http://www.rivingtondesignhouse.com.php53-3.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/HOME-PAGE-WELCOME-2.jpg" />

        </li>



      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end slider -->
```

All the best,

BB

Comment: You need to apply callbacks when the .animate finishes. Right now, it's just one big block... and it runs all at the same time. You need to wait for your animation to finish before animating the rest.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you just need to set the display none into the css rather than at your document ready in the jquery.

eg:

```
#home-slider{
     display:none;
     ...
}
```

this way you arent hiding the element after it loads - it should load hidden then you show it